# Put $f_n: (n(n+1))^{1/p}\chi_{_{[1/(n+1),1/n]}}$ in $\cal { L }_p([0,1],{\cal M},m)$. Prove that $n \neq m$ implies that $|| {f_n - f_m}|| _p \geq 1$.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Consider $\cal { L }_p([0,1],{\cal M},m)$ where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure and $\cal {M}$ is the Lebesgue sigma algebra on $[0,1]$. Define $f_n: (n(n+1))^{1/p}\chi_{_\left[1/(n+1),1/n\right]}$. Prove that $n \neq m$ implies that $||{f_n - f_m}||_p \geq 1$ for $1\leq p < \infty$.

Note that $||f_n - f_m||_p : = \left(\int |f_n - f_m|^p \, dm\right)^{1/p}$ in this space.  Any hints? I haven't been able to make any progress. So far, I know only that $||f_n||_p = 1$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$.

Comment: Well, if $n\neq m$, then $|f_n-f_m| = f_n+f_m$ expect maybe at single points, no?

Comment: Why is that the case?

Comment: Draw the functions. Where are the functions different from zero?

Comment: Thanks for the hint - I see how it works now.

Comment: I would suggest you write an answer yourself, then you see whether you have understood it properly and can get some feedback.